# Connecting 12ga wire to 14ga that is connected to 15 amp breaker

Tags: electrical-panel

I have a ceiling fan and 1 porch light that is connected directly  to a 15 amp breaker. It was installed using 14-2 wire. Then, I have a small basement area that has a 1 light and 4 outlets that I want to power with the same circuit breaker, but this room was wired with 12-2 wire and was covered with finished walls. Question: Can the 12-2 wire be connected to the 14-2 wire, in a junction box, to power the basement.  The 12-2 won't be connected to the 15 amp breaker, the 14-2 will be.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes as long as the breaker is sized for the smallest wire in the circuit you can use a larger gauge and it will even pass inspection. Many of us frown on using smaller wire when the connection in the panel is a larger wire because some one may up size the breaker seeing #12 in the panel not realising there is #14 in the branch some place down the line. But 14 in the panel on a 15 amp breaker going to additional devices wired with #12 is legal. I have done this on lighting circuits when I ran out of 14.

Comment: I do that on every 15A-required circuit because I don't stock #14.

Comment: I usually don't use 14 but on some jobs a couple of spools of 14 can make the difference if I get the job or the amount of profitability. I always have extra 12 as I know I will use it.

Comment: @Harper if you wire a circuit *entirely* in #12, why would you fit a 15-A breaker rather than a 20-A?

Comment: Either because of a regulatory requirement for 15A, or the solitary piece of equipment calls out 15A in its labeling/instructions, or far more likely, there are already 15A breakers in the panel and I don't want to deal with sourcing a 20.  Typicaly the word "pushmatic" is involved in the sourcing issue :)

Comment: @harper we have worked on pushomatic breakers but this is a weak or lame reason to support your statement. I normally use 12 awg wire for everything, even have wired entire homes in #10 as the owner wanted. We both don't like back stabs and they can't be used here in the U.S. with #12 and the cost was not much different in the past so I can agree with that but today to say pushomatic is lame .

Comment: It's our own facility. I wouldn't compromise a customer install.